# Cypher variable length pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphql

I had modeling a timeline like this:

```
(t: Timeline) - [:PREV] -> (t1: Timeline) - [:PREV] -> (t2: Timeline)
```

Each `Timeline` node has a property called `timestamp`.

My time event come from a RabbitMQ, the order is not specified (since all service use async to push to queue) so when new time event come, I need to insert a new time node to the correct spot to maintain my timeline order.

To insert new `Timeline` node to the timeline, I traverse the list with this query: (`headTimestamp` is the latest time node)

```
MATCH (t: Timeline {timestamp: headTimestamp}) - [:PREV*] -> (t1: Timeline)
WHERE t1.timestamp < newTimestamp
RETURN t1
```

I don't find a way to break on the first match. Currently it returns all node with `timestamp < newTimestamp`

How do I do that or is there any work around for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `LIMIT 1` to get the first match:

```
MATCH (t: Timeline {timestamp: headTimestamp}) - [:PREV*] -> (t1: Timeline)
WHERE t1.timestamp < newTimestamp
WITH t1 LIMIT 1
RETURN t1
```

You may want to test to ensure you're getting back the first hit, as usually ordering of results isn't defined unless you use ORDER BY, like so:

```
MATCH path = (t: Timeline {timestamp: headTimestamp}) - [:PREV*] -> (t1: Timeline)
WHERE t1.timestamp < newTimestamp
WITH t1 
ORDER BY length(path) ASC
LIMIT 1
RETURN t1
```

Comment: As I understand, LIMIT applied after the result is calculated, it does not short-circuit right?

Comment: LIMIT will allow short circuiting if possible, you can PROFILE the query to see it in action. The first query I provided should only grab the first match and then stop traversing. The second query provided has to order by the length of the path, so all results must be obtained to sort first.

Comment: Apparently not. Use query plan I see that the LIMIT clause comes after the var expand all (which access all nodes in my list)

Comment: It may be listed after the expand all operation, but it will lazily grab the results it finds up to the given limit and then stop, and if there are such matches you should see that reflected in the db hits. If there are no such matches, however, or if those matches are found only near the end of exhausting all possible results, then you may see less of a reduction than you think. See how the PROFILE looks as far as db hits if you remove your WHERE clause for example.

Comment: Tha'ts the case. Thanks